# How to show datepicker on click of textfield in titanium?

Tags: datepicker, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am able to show datepicker. But on native application User click the textfield and date picker is open .So I need to implement that functionality using titanium platform. can you suggest a way or give some example .When user click textfield it don't show keyboard only show datepicker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple just add a datepicker in runtime.

Go through this link Demonstrates all

[Datepicker on click of text box](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137652/date-picker-for-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `editable` property of your textfield to false, then call your picker in the "click" callback of the textfield.

```
var textfield = Ti.UI.createTextField ({
    editable: false // That way the keyboard won't show up
    //your other textfield properties
});

textfield.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    showDatePicker();
});
```